# nginx: regex matching of not equal?

Tags: nginx

is there a "not" equivalent for nginx matches?  I am thinking

```
location !~ "\.(html|php)$" {
    deny all;
}
```

to allow serving only html and php files.  the alternative is "deny all" followed by a ~ with "allow all".  alas, this seems to interfere somehow with some earlier location magic in my nginx file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use nested location logic like that:

```
location / {
  deny all;
  location ~* "\.(html|php)$" {
    Allow all;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

regexped locations also match by their order. So you could also use something like this:

`location ~* "\.(html|php)$" { ...; break; }
 location ~* "." { deny all; }`

Notice the second location must also be regexp-based.

Comment: I think it's best to use nginx configuration functional, order independent style, as it's supposed to be.

Comment: Only Igor Sysoev can say what is "supposed to be" and what is not. Others chose what is simplier for them to understand.

Comment: Igor is not the only one who develops Nginx. If you read other people's posts (like Maxim Dounin, Yichun Zhang and many others) order-independent is the preferred, orthodox way of writing nginx configuration.